# SyntaxError when sending python async function to interactive in visual studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017, python-asyncio

I'm experiencing a problem with the send to interactive feature in visual studio community 2017.

Every time I'm sending async function to the interactive window, I get an error.
for example:

```
async def test():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

If I select this function and send it to interactive, I get:

```
>>> async def test():
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    async def test():
                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>> await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The same function work in the same interactive window when I type the function in there directly, using `Shift+Enter` to make a new line.

It seems as if it is being sent line by line, instead of all the function at once.
But it only happens with async functions.